# Select & Query contents of table in PlayWright .Net

Tags: c#, .net, playwright

I just started learning PlayWright with .Net and have trouble with query table. What is the right selector to select & query a table then get its contents?
[image]

This is the table, the contents of this table are in `<tbody>`, and I want to get it. How can I do it? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector:

```
(//table)[X]/tbody/tr[Y]
```

Depending on what table you want to use you can change the selector

First table second row:

```
(//table)[1]/tbody/tr[2]
```

Second table first row:

```
(//table)[2]/tbody/tr[1]
```

For the header of the table, Second table the only header row:

```
(//table)[2]/thead/tr[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I tried to write as you said but It still have some bugs. 
This is what I wrote: `var locator = Page.Locator(selector: ("table-responsive"[1] / tbody / tr[2]))`
Can you tell me what I was wrong here?